# Email notification for Alfresco discussion

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want alfresco to send email to site members when a new discussion thread is added to the site. I have gone through some help material for email notification generation including [alfresco share discussion notification](http://jared.ottleys.net/alfresco/alfresco-share-discussion-notification).

I have created a JS file with mail action code, have created discussion email template as well. But I have some confusion (actually lack of knowledge). When/how this JS would be called? How would alfresco know that it has to execute newly created JS file's code. Please explain this point.

Comment: Don't you need to set up a rule on the discussion site component to run your JS?

Comment: you mean following rule in 'web-client-config-custom.xml' file? Yes, I have added this rule as well. Is this all?? **`<alfresco-config>
    <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Action Wizards">
        <subtypes>
            <type name="fm:post"/>
            <type name="fm:topic"/>
        </subtypes>
    </config>
</alfresco-config>`**

Comment: No, I meant go into Share, use the repository browser, call up the folder details on the discussion component, then add a rule there like you might do for a document library folder